# Sum of unique rows of joined table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables. `practices`, `adjustments` and `claims`.
I need to select all practices with additional column `adjustments.amount + count(claims.id)`

Here is my query.

```
SELECT 
 practices.*,
 (
   SUM(adjustments.amount) + count(claims.id)
 ) as accurred_fees
  INNER JOIN adjustments ON adjustments.practice_id = practices.id 
  INNER JOIN claims ON claims.practice_id = practices.id
 GROUP BY practices.id
```

In my database I have 1 practice, 20 claims and 1 adjustment with amount equal to `2`. `SUM(eligible_fee_adjustments.amount)` in query always returns 40, I guess it's 2 * count(claims.id), I don't know why it behaves like that. Could you please help me to find solution. Thanks in advance

Comment: can u post the tables and some data in http://sqlfiddle.com and the expected result to ur question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a problem of joining along two different dimensions, so the rows are multiplying.  You can solve this by pre-aggregating the data.  The following will fix this particular problem:

```
SELECT p.*,
       (SUM(a.amount) + c.cnt) as accurred_fees
FROM practices p INNER JOIN
     adjustments a
     ON a.practice_id = p.id INNER JOIN
     (SELECT practice_id, count(*) as cnt
      FROM claims c
      GROUP BY practice_id
     ) c
     ON c.practice_id = p.id
GROUP BY p.id;
```

You should probably preaggregate the adjustments as well:

```
SELECT p.*,
       (a.amount + c.cnt) as accurred_fees
FROM practices p INNER JOIN
     (SELECT practice_id, SUM(amount) as amount
      FROM adjustments a
      GROUP BY practice_id
     ) a
     ON a.practice_id = p.id INNER JOIN
     (SELECT practice_id, count(*) as cnt
      FROM claims c
      GROUP BY practice_id
     ) c
     ON c.practice_id = p.id
GROUP BY p.id;
```

And you might want to consider `LEFT OUTER JOIN` rather than `INNER JOIN` so you get all practices, even those that might be missing adjustments or claims.

Comment: Thanks a lot, your approach helped me a lot. But what should I do if I  have 4th table which is joined through ``claims`` table? In my case I have 4th table ``submissions`` which is joined through ``claims`` table(doble join). What should I do If I want to use count of ``submissions`` in my calculations too?

Comment: @Pavel . . . Without additional information, I would suggest that you add the submissions as a subquery to the `c` subquery for claims.